Error message saying "Unable to update gnome-42-2204"
I am very new. I just unpacked a second-hand computer with Ubuntu partition from storage. When trying to download all the Ubuntu updates, I am getting mostly either kicked off the wireless connection or get error messages such as:
&nbsp;&nbsp;Unable to update gnome-42-2204:   
&nbsp;&nbsp;(null): cannot refresh "gnome-42-2204":   
&nbsp;&nbsp;persistent network error: Post "h<span>t</span>tps://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh":  
&nbsp;&nbsp;dial tcp:lookup api.snapcraft.io: Temporary failure in name resolution


If you run 22.04, the gnome version should be 42.9

Thank you.  Also found that when I disabled the Ipv6 connection, it seemed to connect better, and the error message has not repeated.  Thanks again for taking the time to help a newbie! Have a good day!

Its helpful if you're specific with details; you've not provided your Ubuntu product & release details.  If you're using a LTS release, you have kernel stack options, but we won't know what options you have until we know what you're running (and more specific than Ubuntu)  The Temporary failure in name resolution may mean its temporary as the error states; if your updates included newer networking the updates may have required your wifi to be reset (ie. connection lost briefly) during update application too. A simple repeated update may complete everything.

Thank you.  Am using Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS.  GNOME version is 42.9.  Windowing system is Wayland. Thank you again.  Am getting there, very slowly, with lots of re-starts.  Will look up kernel stack options.  ; )  Appreciate it.

I suggest applying upgrades & security fixes to your system asap, as if your system reports as 22.04.3 then you've not applied them in some time, or that is a clue as to your problem. This post ( https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/ ) shows the ISO release date of 22.04.4, but installed systems upgraded before that ISO release date.  This is a Q&A site & not a forum, please add additional details to your question, as its your question that is answered; comments get removed once addressed   You should return to basics & apply fixes asap and retest.

I'd suggest sudo apt update and read the output, ensure there are no warning or error messages, and all expected lines are present, then apply fixes with sudo apt upgrade (or sudo apt full-upgrade if required due to sources you've added etc) to ensure all security fixes are applied, then reboot & retest.  22.04.3 shows you're behind on applying fixes (or your details are incorrect, but we're limited to details you provide). When fully upgraded you'll have fewer problems, though temporary issues can still sometimes occur.

Thank you, yes, it took several days and multiple re-boots. I picked smaller updates first. If they worked, continued to apply others until the process stalled.  If they didn't work, just re-booted and let the automatic patches go on, then tried again.  Finally it seems all is well.  Many thanks for the guidance and detailed help.  Appreciate it! : )

Feel free to write up your own answer then, you can reference or refer to any advice given if you wish, but try and write what you think will be useful for subsequent readers who may find them in the exact spot you were in when you sought out help. This question will then be answered; and you can gain some rep if/when you accept your own written answer as the answer to your question.  (this is a Q&A site, not a forum).

Thank you to all who offered responses. In the end, time and doing updates 1 at a time, avoiding the largest ones or any that didn't work at first, and moving on to those that would install seems to have solved it.  It had been about a year since the computer had been connected to the internet.  Each update or security patch needed its own allotment of time and re-start, but the computer did work again and is now up-to-date after several days.
